# C #define string, Servname not supported for ai_socktype

Tags: c, string, sockets, c-preprocessor

I am trying to write socket program in C. My entire code works fine when I do

```
#define PORT "3333"
```

but not

```
#define PORT getParameter("setting.ini","PORT")
```

Basically, the getParameter just opens the setting.ini file and read through, look for the variable and its value then return it. The only reason I am doing this is because I don't want the port number to be hardcoded in my code. I got:

> "Servname not supported for ai_socktype"

I have no clue what causes this error. 
Any ideas?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *substring(char* str, int start, int length) {
    char *newString = (char *)malloc(length * sizeof(char)+1);
    int i, x = 0;
    int end=start+length-1;
    for(i = start ; i <= end; i++)
        newString[x++] = str[i];
    newString[x] = '\0';
    return newString;
}

char *getParameter(char *fName, char *pName)
{
   FILE *fr;
   char line[80];
   int i;

   fr = fopen (fName, "r");  /* open the file for reading */

   while(fgets(line, 80, fr) != NULL)
   {
   i = strcspn (line,"=");
   if(strcmp(pName,substring(line,0,i))==0){
            char *value = substring(line,i+1,strlen(line)-i);
            fclose(fr);
            return value;
        }
   }
   fclose(fr);
}

int main(void){
    char *PORT = getParameter("setting.ini","PORT");
    const int BACKLOG = atoi(getParameter("setting.ini","BACKLOG"));
    printf("%s\n",PORT);
    printf("%d\n",BACKLOG);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is related to line feeds. Your strings when you hard code them don't include a line feed, but when you read them using `fgets()`, the way you are parsing them retains any trailing `\n`. It's possible that confuses whatever you're passing the value to to get that error.

Aside from that, you have a number of memory leaks in your code as the results of your `substring()` calls are never freed (and you don't even keep a pointer to them so they could be freed in some cases).

Answer (score 0):

First - make sure value which is fetched by your function is really what you expect it to be and doesn't contain any special characters like end-of-line or similar.

Also, regardless whether this will solve your problem or not, I would recommend to change your approach - not use #define, but make PORT a variable instead which you'll fill using your getParameter function somewhere in your code upon program startup. That would feel like a better approach to me.